# Constructor overloading with boost::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

Consider the following .h file:

```
#ifndef COM_H_
#define COM_H_

#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <map>

class B;

class A : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<A>{
public:
    A(){}
    ~A(){}

    void Init();

    boost::shared_ptr<B> b_ptr_;
};

class B : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<B>{
public:

    B(){}
    B(boost::shared_ptr<A> a_ptr);
    B(int j, boost::shared_ptr<A> a_ptr);
    ~B(){}

    void Init();
    void Init(boost::shared_ptr<A> a_ptr);
    void Init(int j, boost::shared_ptr<A> a_ptr);

    std::string b;
    boost::shared_ptr<A> a_ptr_;
};
#endif /* COM_H_ */
```

and the .cc file:

```
#include "com.h"

void A::Init() {

    // Case 1 not working
    // boost::shared_ptr<B> b1(new B(shared_from_this()));
    // b1->Init();

    // Case 2 working
    boost::shared_ptr<B> b2(new B());
    b2->Init(shared_from_this());
}

B::B(boost::shared_ptr<A> a_ptr) {
    B(2, a_ptr);
}

B::B(int j, boost::shared_ptr<A> a_ptr) {
    a_ptr_ = a_ptr;
    b = "b";
}

void B::Init() {
    a_ptr_->b_ptr_ = shared_from_this();
}

void B::Init(boost::shared_ptr<A> a_ptr) {
    Init(2, a_ptr);
}

void B::Init(int j, boost::shared_ptr<A> a_ptr) {

    a_ptr_ = a_ptr;
    b = "b";
    a_ptr_->b_ptr_ = shared_from_this();
}
```

In main:

```
#include "com.h"
#include <iostream>
int main() {

    boost::shared_ptr<A> a(new A());
    a->Init();

    std::cout << a->b_ptr_->b << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When passing a boost::shared_ptr to a constructor and then calling another (overloaded) constructor with the same pointer as argument, the object pointed by the shared_ptr is lost and the error

> terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl
>
> > '   what():  tr1::bad_weak_ptr

is thrown. The same does not happen when calling two overloaded functions (Init) in the same fashion.

Can anyone please explain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling shared_from_this() during B's construction, which is forbidden because the shared pointer to B hasn't been initialized at that time.

Specifically, this constructor is the one you're calling:

```
B::B(boost::shared_ptr<A> a_ptr) {
    Init(2, a_ptr);  // runtime error -- Init(...) calls shared_from_this!
}
```

---

Answer Part 2:

I suspect you're used to another language :)  In C++ you cannot call another constructor in the way you are trying to do.  The line

```
B(2, a_ptr);
```

is not doing what you think -- all it's doing is constructing a temporary B object which is immediately destroyed.  It won't call the other constructor.  So you're ending up with a B that still has a default constructed a_ptr_ member.

C++-11, if your compiler supports it, has delegating constructors, which would look like this:

```
B(shared_ptr<A> a_ptr) : B(2, a_ptr) {...}
```

... Otherwise you have to declare another function and have both constructors call it.

Comment: Ok, you are right! I edited the code so that the constructor you mentioned calls the overloaded constructor where shared_from_this() is not called. Now I get an error that Assertion failed: (px != 0), function operator->, file /usr/local/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp, line 414.

Comment: It's right there, I edited the Original post. The constructor doesn't call Init anymore, it calls B(2, a_ptr).

`B::B(boost::shared_ptr<A> a_ptr) {
    B(2, a_ptr);
}`

Comment: @apon Ok I think I see the other problem, see my answer edit.

Comment: Ok, that explains it! Thanks a lot!